# Contractible pieces of $GL(n,\mathbb{C})$

Tags: general-topology, matrices, topological-groups

Is $GL(n,\mathbb{C})$ contractible for any $n$?

My intuition is telling me it is not, because the determinant maps the general linear to $\mathbb{C}\setminus 0$ which is not contractible. If there was an homotopy of a cycle in $GL_n$ to a point, the determinant would map this to an analogous homotopy in $\mathbb{C}\setminus 0$. Is there any missing subtlety to this argument?

My real question is: **how do write the complex general linear group as the union of finitely many contractible patches?**

I am interested in explicit descriptions of the covering.

**EDIT**:
The problem has been reduced (in the comments) to covering $U(n)$.

Comment: Your argument with the determinant works perfectly well.  Of particular importance is the fact that the map is onto.

Comment: What kind of patches are you looking for?  Bounded patches?  Finitely many patches?

Comment: Finitely many patches! It is for a classification problem I am working on, so few and easy to describe patches would help greatly. Even better if there is a 'geometric sense'.

Comment: You have to show that the map $\det$ is not null-homotopic. You want to show that there's a loop in $GL(n,\mathbb C)$ that maps to a nontrivial (non-nullhomotopic) loop in $\mathbb C \setminus 0$.

Comment: $GL(n,\mathbb C)$, as a Lie group, is homeomorphic to $\mathbb R^N \times K$, where $K$ is its maximal compact subgroup. Here we get $\mathbb R^{n^2} \times U(n)$. Because $U(n)$ is compact you can cover it with finitely many charts $U_i$, and thus cover $GL(n,\mathbb C)$ with the charts $\mathbb R^{n^2} \times U_i$. I don't know how many you need. For $U(1)$ you need two, for $U(2)$ I think you need four.

Comment: @Temitope.A For the loop that Mike is talking about: consider $t \mapsto e^{it} I$, where $I$ denotes the identity.  My first comment was mistaken since I missed that hole in your proof.

Comment: Yeah, it is clear. Also I believe proving that it is onto is also clear and easily implies the thesis.
What about the patches of $U(n)$? References for that?

Comment: Any compact manifold has a finite open cover of open balls. Just pick all the possible open balls, and use compactness to find a finite subcover. Open balls, by definition, are contractible. I only know how many you need for $U(1)$ and $U(2)$ by inspection.

Comment: @MikeMiller  I am aware of that. But I am interested in an explicit description of these balls. This question is just a step in my problem and I would like to get and carry over as much information as possible to use elsewhere. For example $U(1)\cong S^1$, am I right? I could say $U(1)=Re(z)>0\cup Re(z)<0 \cup Im(z)>0 \cup Im(z)<0$, where $z$ is the unique entry in a $1\times 1$ matrix.

Comment: Correct. For $U(2)$, I know that $U(2)$ fits into a fiber sequence $U(1) \to U(2) \to SU(2)$. $SU(2)$ is homeomorphic to $S^3$. Trivialize this fiber bundle over the northern and southern hemispheres to get a covering of $U(2)$ by two copies of $B^3 \times S^1$. Now you have a covering of $U(2)$ by four copies of $B^3 \times I$, which is homeomorphic to an open 4-ball. I think in general it's probably going to be very hard to get an efficient covering of $U(n)$ by balls.

Comment: @Temitope.A onto alone is generally insufficient, as it turns out.